# File difference between commits in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide, diff, jetbrains-ide

I have noticed that in IntelliJ there is some kind of diff tool

[image]

Unfortunately, this kind of instrument seems only to show differences between common files

[image]

I think it should be more useful something that shows also the files present on one commit but not in the other, and vice versa, like "diff" function between normal commits. I have tried to select inner folders for compare, but nothing. Do you know at least any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the only possible solution is to raise the problem to Jetbrains, and wait.

Please upvote the ticket if you want it implemented.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268404